# Como fazer o Python 3.7 reconhecer as bibliotecas instaladas no Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho instalado no meu computador o *Python 3.6* há tempos.

Hoje instalei o *Python 3.7.2*. Mas, ao rodar o `import numpy as np`, deu o seguinte erro:

> no module named numpy

No *Python 3.6* não ocorre este erro.

Como fazer o *Python 3.7.2* acessar os módulos usados pelo *Python 3.6*?

Comment: Tentou `pip install numpy`?

Comment: Acho que vc tem que instalar no python 3.7 via pip

Answer (score 4):

Você não pode usar as mesmas bibliotecas - as que são compiladas para Python 3.6 vão funcionar só naquela versão.

No entanto é tranquilo instalar de novo as mesmas bibliotecas para o Python 3.7 -

Você não disse como instalou o python3.7, nem qual sistema está usando. mas se souber a pasta dele - é só usar o pip *pra ele* . Eventualmente você pode ler sobre virtualenv e sempre criar virtualenv's novos -

A principio deve dar pra digitar:

```
python3.7 -m ensurepip
python3.7 -m pip install numpy
```

Se estiver no Linux, e instalou o Python em um prefixo do sistema (e não na sua pasta de usuário), pode precisar colocar o "sudo" antes dos comandos acima.

Em tempo: para bibliotecas que sejam compostas apenas de arquivos `.py`, sem nada compilado até é possível compartilhar a instalação entre versões diferentes do Python (e não é o caso do *numpy*) - mas isso requer um gerenciamento cuidadoso de pastas em que bibliotecas usadas pelas duas versões estão instaladas, bem como ter sempre certeza de que bibliotecas que tenham módulos compilados nunca estejam nessa pasta compartilhada: simplesmente não vale a pena.

**Em geral, se faz justamente o contrário**: para cada projeto usando Python (e um desenvolvedor backend numa empresa que use micro-serviços pode ter *dezenas* de projetos distintos), se cria um *virtualenv*, onde *todas* as bibliotecas são instaladas - nas versões corretas necessárias para cada projeto específico. Isso garante que não haja conflito de versões de bibliotecas entre projetos diferentes.